# Div height does not resize when add more content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a kind of `tag-cloud`.
I've a div (the **tag container**) in which dinamically I add span nodes (the *tags*).

`span` nodes are default inline elements, so if I've set their `display` property do `display:block`, to prevent that they will overflow the div horizontally.

I've also set their `float` property to `float:left` since I want that they're disposed near on the same line and if line is full tthey automatically go to the next line.

The problem now is that, the tags overflow vertically on the bottom. The tag container does not resize its height to contain all the tags inserted. How could I fix this problem?

**EDIT**
Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Vk92s/1/

As you can see, if a comment `float: left`, the div automatically resize, but all the tags dispose on a new line.
At opposite, if i add the `float: left`, the tags wrap correctly, but div does not resize.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFNah/2/).

You can set `overflow` to `hidden`, like below:

```
<div id="test"> 
    <span>first</span> 
    <span>second </span> 
    <span>third </span> 
    <span>fourth </span> 
</div> 

#test
{
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 100px; 
   overflow: hidden; 
}
span
{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I've always been bothered about needing a `clear` node that's semantically useless.  Are there any gotchas about using `overflow: hidden;` instead of clearing the float?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a div that has `clear: both` set under all of your elements.

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/derleek/EaPqB/7/)

### HTML

```
<div id="tag-cloud">
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <span class="tag">example</span>
    <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.tag{
    display: block;
    width: 98px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
}
.clear-both{
    clear: both;
}
#tag-cloud{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Actually, your fiddle does not include your `clear: both` solution.

Comment: ha, weird i must not have saved it.

Answer (score 3):

In your tag container div, add this css rule:

```
overflow: auto;
```

This will make it expand to contain its floated content.

**Edit:**

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5AgxU/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding an empty element that clears your float, my preference is to use the following on the parent element so you don't pollute your markup.

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   line-height: 0;
   height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
   display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
   display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
   height: 1%;
   overflow: visible;
}
```